# Connected React Router - Don't update the view

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I kinda need an advice here ... I'm learning how to build a full app based on react.
Here is the test app : https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-platform-46sjl

Using React , Redux, Saga and typescript.

Everything work so far except the routing :

-Custon event are fired : onClick={() => redirectRequest('/')}

-When I manually try to access an url : /starwars for example : that work

-The router event is fired too in redux devtool : https://snipboard.io/uWaokq.jpg

-The Url change and the {location} in props + state is updated

-The view is not updating --> don't show the other components

I checked a lot of github issues / other stack questions but nothing seem to make it work so far.
Maybe you guy will have an idea of what I am missing here.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Can you present the app in a codesandbox? In codesandbox.io

Comment: Done :) Didn't knew that it was simple to do it from a git ;)

Comment: Are you defining which component to render for an URL?

Comment: /src/app/features/router/router.component.tsx --> Yep : there

Each button fire an action to saga that take care of the redirection : /src/app/store/sagas/router.saga.ts

Comment: When you try to access https://46sjl.csb.app/starwars --> it work. But not with the click on the button

Comment: Try using another component of react-router-dom. Add "import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';" and "return (<NavLink className="navbar-link" to="/">Home</NavLink>)" in the render.

Comment: Or if you want to navigate programmatically using react-router-dom, you can do `history.push('/mypage')`

Answer (score 0):

Use **NavLink** as imported from react-router-dom

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Later use it as follows in your render function

```
render () {
    return (
        ...
                <NavLink className="navlink" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: That actually work better but don't fire my custom event action  anymore :/